# Rename File extension from .tmp to .txt

Tags: vba

I see there is a filecopy class that is a member of the filesystem but I wanted to just change the file extension. Is the class that will rename the file name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this macro you can rename all `.tmp` files in a folder to `.txt`.

Take a look at the VBA [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264639.aspx) method:

> The Name statement renames a file and moves it to a different
>   directory or folder, if necessary. Name can move a file across drives,
>   but it can only rename an existing directory or folder when both
>   newpathname and oldpathname are located on the same drive. Name cannot
>   create a new file, directory, or folder.

**Code:**

```
Sub rename_files()

    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String, NewName As String, i As Integer

    MyFolder = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test_folder\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.tmp")

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        i = InStrRev(MyFile, ".")
        NewName = Left(MyFile, i - 1) & ".txt"
        Name MyFolder & MyFile As MyFolder & NewName
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I got a compile error while testing this. Which is odd.

Comment: It's working fine here... `Excel 2010, VBA 7.0.1637`

Comment: Probably a missing  reference library or something. Thanks for your contribute.

Comment: I recommend here `InstrRev` instead of `Instr`, since a file's name *may* contain multiple dots and we have to find the *last* dot, which precedes the file's extension.

Comment: @A.S.H I really appreciate your hint! Thanks for this information! Just improved my answer. Now it works with files that contains multiple dots.